# makeSceneTransitionAnimation back button glitch

Tags: android, animation, android-intent, back-button, transition

I'm creating an Android app with a timeline. I used a `ListView` to create the timeline effect. When I click on a `ListViewItem` I use `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` to show the detailed view. Everything works fine, except when I am in the detailed view and I press the back button, the `makeSceneTransitionAnimations` animates the page to the row above the originally clicked row and the screen flashes afterwards.

This is the code I use to create the animation:

```
    View timelineObject = view.findViewById(R.id.transition);
    timelineObject.setTransitionName("selectClientTransition");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);

    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, timelineObject , "selectClientTransition");
    this.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

I tried overriding the back button in my detailed activity but I don't see a way to pass the position of the listview item as a parameter to the `makeSceneTransitionAnimation`.

Comment: Are you using emulator or mobile for run the app

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        Explode explode = new Explode();
        getWindow().setExitTransition(explode);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    


/*------Your code When the list item is click------*/
Intent intent = new Intent(context1, Main_testcollapse.class);
                intent.putExtra("time", list.get(pos).getTime());
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    ActivityOptions activityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context1, view, "cardname");
                    startActivity(intent, activityOptions.toBundle());
                } else {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Another Activity Inside of onCreate

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);
        Slide slide=new Slide(Gravity.END);
        getWindow().setReturnTransition(slide);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to handle backpressed, because **makeSceneTransitionAnimation** method itself taken care of that.

For your case simply override onItemClick of the listview.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                this,
                new Pair(view.findViewById(R.id.**id_of_your_list_view_item**),
                        "detail:image");
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, activityOptions.toBundle());
}
```

> **id_of_your_list_view_item**: Animation start from this ID and Animation will fall back to this ID when user clicks back button.

DetailViewActivity onCreate method will have the following code

```
ImageView mHeaderImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_header);
```

`ViewCompat.setTransitionName(mHeaderImageView, "detail:image");`

**"detail:image"** is Identification of the target view